# getting xml data from url in php

Tags: php, html, xml, jquery

I need one help, I have a form after submitting the form, the action url return the an xml data to the browser, i want to get the xml data to a variable. unable to fetch, i tried following code

```
$( "#searchForm" ).submit(function( event ) {
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "my_remote_url",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: xmlParser
    });

})
function xmlParser(xml) {
console.log(xml);
}
```

shows an error of access control CORS error on console, please guide me to retrieve the data

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
//datatype:"xml",it is not needed
success: function(res){
alert(res);//this will alert the response if ajax is success.
}
```

Comment: Nope this is not working in my case, could you please elaborate little

Comment: Is your ajax success or error?

Comment: success but no return the console.log value...